# Emacs regex extract path

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to write a regex which gives me the index of the path before a certain folder, as instance :

```
"/1/2/projects/myproject/application_self_service/development_settings.py"
```

Should return the index 5 so I can extract the path from the string using (substring 0 5 string)

I am banging my head here, in fact :

```
(string-match-p (regexp-quote ".*\\project") "/1/2/projects/myproject/application_self_service/development_settings.py")
```

Return nil all the time.... What is wrong ?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use `regexp-quote` in this circumstance?  Also, why are you using two backslashes before the word "project"?

Comment: I am escaping the backslash.I am not a real ELisp expert so feel free to answer with an alternative solution

Comment: I didn't see a backslash in the string `"/1/2/projects/myproject/application_self_service/development_settings.py"` so that is why I asked about your intended usage.  If there is no reason to include a backslash, then remove it.  Likewise, if there is no reason to include `regexp-quote` in this case, then remove it.  Consider placing your test string to be matched in a `*scratch*` buffer, and then type `M-x re-builder`.  In the `*RE-Builder*` buffer, type in between the double-quotes (that should already be there) `.*project`  and then play with it a bit and adjust the regexp as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the regexp you want is just `"/projects"`.  On the path you provided,

```el
(string-match-p
 "/projects"
 "/1/2/projects/myproject/application_self_service/development_settings.py")
```

returns 4, and

```el
(substring "/1/2/projects/myproject/application_self_service/development_settings.py" 0 4)
```

returns `"/1/2"`.  (As an aside, note that you had the arguments to `substring` in the wrong order.)

Finally, some comments on why your original approach didn't work:

1. First off, `regexp-quote` takes a string and produces a regexp matching only that string (per its documentation; try `C-h f regexp-quote`).  In this case, your `string-match-p` call would only return non-nil if the string contained `".*\projects"` (period and asterisk included) as a literal substring.
2. Secondly, as I'm sure you've noticed by now, your path used forward slashes as delimiters, not backslashes.
3. Finally, you don't want to include the leading `".*"` in the regexp because, even in the event of a match, `string-match-p` would just return 0, because the start of the match would always be at the start of the string.